# How do I differentiate when a child LWC component is called twice in the parent component?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I have a parent component where I am calling a child component twice in LWC.

I am firing an API method in the child from the parent, but it is firing for only one child component, not the other one.

#### Parent component HTML markup

```
<template>

    // First child component
    <c-child-component><c-child component>

    // Second child component
    <c-child-component><c-child component>
</template>
```

#### Child `@api` method

```
@api handleShowError{
    this.showError=true
}
```

I have made changes in the Playground. You can check here: [PlayGround](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/Yrs6t0YY7/18/edit)

Comment: We don't have enough code to help you. As far as I can tell, this shouldn't even compile or run. Can you please create a [playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground) that demonstrates what you're trying to achieve? Please [edit] the link in to your question. Thanks!

Comment: @sfdcfox I have updated Playground Link. Please check it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this.template.querySelector` will identify only the 1st component/element. When you need to identify all the components/elements, you need to use `querySelectorAll`.

You can try below:

```
this.template.querySelectorAll('c-child').forEach((comp) => comp.showError());
```

Also for more learning, you can check below links:

1. https://salesforcesas.home.blog/2019/07/25/lwc-access-templates-and-methods-of-child-components/
2. https://salesforcesas.home.blog/2019/07/16/lwc-selectors-identification-of-elements/

Comment: It worked. A slight change in code:- this.template.querySelectorAll('c-child').forEach(comp => comp.showError());